# Lua using optional table values with the C API

Tags: c, lua

I am passing a table { Value1=100, Value2=200, Value3=300, ...} from Lua to C. The following works great for my required values:

```
// Get the values from the table
lua_getfield(L, 2, "Value1");
lua_getfield(L, 2, "Value2");
lua_getfield(L, 2, "Value3");

const char *value_3 = luaL_checkstring(L, -1);
const char *value_2 = luaL_checkstring(L, -2);
const char *value_1 = luaL_checkstring(L, -3);
```

But I need to handle optional fields in the table, some of which may not be known at compile time - but will be known at run-time. Based on all my searches, I think I need to use a metatable to replace the __index method on the table operated on by lua_getfield() to return NIL rather than throwing an error if a particular key is not found. Then I could use luaL_checktype() to test for that.

I have used metatables with userdata with good success. But despite that, I really have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: Does `lua_getfield` throw an error?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Almost perfect problem statement, except you need to actually ask a question.

Comment: No, but luaL_checkstring() would throw an error. Version 5.2 lua_getfield() was a void function. That changed in 5.3 and it now returns the type, including nil/0 if the key is not found in the table. I am using 5.3 library, but was referring to 5.2 Reference manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate things. If you want to produce the default value in Lua, go for the metatable, but if you can get it in C, it is very easy. `lua_getfield` produces `nil` if the key cannot be found in the table, so you can compare its return value with `LUA_TNIL` to check if it returned nil (or `lua_isnil` if you use an older API). In that case, use your default value, or proceed with `luaL_checkstring` as usual.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem is that I was referring to the 5.2 Reference Manual which I bought a printed copy of. In version 5.2 lua_getfield() is a void function. I appears that changed in 5.3 - which is what I am actually using.  And yes, simply checking the return value will solve my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, in Lua 5.2 and older, you can use `lua_type` on the value which would give you the same result.